# Convert DStreams to RDDs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

How can I convert Spark Streaming DStream to RDDs so that be used inside Spark Context & not inside Streaming Context? Using Python.

Here is the error I am getting: 
AttributeError: 'TransformedDStream' object has no attribute 'foreach'

```
def result(y):
  return y


d_stream = input_stream.map(lambda x : mainReduce(x)).map(lambda q: q)

rdd = d_stream.foreach(result)
```

Comment: `DStream` is an abstraction over a collection of RDDs. Maybe you're looking for `dStream.foreachRDD`?

Comment: Thanks. Please have a look at the above code & the error that I am receiving.

Comment: `foreachRDD`, not `foreach`

Comment: Thanks a lot....................................